# Symfony: Register user if he has not account yet with LDAP authentification

Tags: symfony, ldap

im having a LDAP server and symfony application. The application will connect to LDAP and authentificate the user against LDAP. If the authentification is successful, it will load the rest of the user data from local application database based on MySQL.

The problem occurs when there is first sign in for some user. They have their identity in LDAP and that can be confirmed during login, but their user is not yet created in the symfony application database. I would like to create a new user with some default information when this situation occurs.

I have not found any way to do it yet, so im open to any suggestions.

Comment: Obviously, the answer to this is a custom user provider, so ill share an example of that later on.

Answer (score 0):

Example custom user provider that will register new users if its authentificated from LDAP and does not exist in database.

```
    <?php
// src/Security/UserProvider.php
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Symfony calls this method if you use features like switch_user
     * or remember_me.
     *
     * If you're not using these features, you do not need to implement
     * this method.
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     *
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException if the user is not found
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $em = $this->em;
        $user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));
        if ($user) {
            return $user;
        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $user;
        // Load a User object from your data source or throw UsernameNotFoundException.
        // The $username argument may not actually be a username:
        // it is whatever value is being returned by the getUsername()
        // method in your User class.
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: fill in loadUserByUsername() inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    /**
     * Refreshes the user after being reloaded from the session.
     *
     * When a user is logged in, at the beginning of each request, the
     * User object is loaded from the session and then this method is
     * called. Your job is to make sure the user's data is still fresh by,
     * for example, re-querying for fresh User data.
     *
     * If your firewall is "stateless: false" (for a pure API), this
     * method is not called.
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Invalid user class "%s".', get_class($user)));
        }

        if (!$refreshedUser = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->find($user->getId())) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User with id %s not found', json_encode($user->getId())));
        }

        return $refreshedUser;
    }

    /**
     * Tells Symfony to use this provider for this User class.
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

You also have to configure the security.yml to use this provider

```
providers:
# used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
  app_user_provider:
    id: App\Security\UserProvider
```